# I want to send a file attachment using Excel Macro

Tags: excel

I want to attach a file to an e-mail I am setting up in an Excel Macro

the file is for a location financial variance report and I have used the following nomenclature when I create the file:

LOCATIONNAME-DDMMMYYY

thus I have a location called San Diego and the file name is SANDIEGO-28FEB2017.XLS

The file name will change based on the drop down choices I have set up.

How can I attach those files to an e-mail I create in the macro.    I am a total novice at this so I thank any one who can assist me.

Comment: I think this is what u r looking for-http://ccm.net/faq/7780-excel-a-macro-to-send-mail-with-attachments

Comment: This might also help: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail2.htm